# Why is my Javascript RegEx quantifier "not working"?

Tags: javascript, regex

This question seems to have such an easy answer and an ashaming one for me, that I hope you just comment, then I can delete the thread after solving. ;)

I have a problem with the `{n}` quantifier in my RegEx. It does not seem to work!

Here my code

```
document.time.Id.onkeyup = function() {
  var that = this.value,
      regex = /^[1-9]{1}/
  if (that) {   
      if (!that.match(regex)) {
          this.nextSibling.innerHTML="Number must be between '1' and '100'.";
      } else {
          this.nextSibling.innerHTML="";
      }
  } else {
      this.nextSibling.innerHTML="";
  } 
}
```

As you can see, I want to match against 1 till 100 in the end, but I am stuck at the bit, that the quantifier does not work. When I key in 0 there is a match failure, as well with any letter...so it does work "a bit".

Can you please help me?

Comment: First of all, why are you using RegEx for this? :)

Comment: @thefourtheye I need to validate on the client side, that the number is between 1 and 100. It is actually a homework, so I have to use it, but what other ways would there be? ;)

Comment: You can just check if `that` is a number and if it is within 0 and 100 or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this regex instead:

```
^[1-9][0-9]?$|^100$
```

The quantifier you used is actually redundant, since `[1-9]` and `[1-9]{1}` mean the same thing.

If you input `1000` with your current code and regex, the number will pass because a match counts as long as the regex matches any part of the string. Using `$` (end of line anchor) forces the regex to check the whole string.

But you should probably be using a simple `if` check for that.

```
if (that > 0 && that <= 100 && that % 1 == 0) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Note that your regex doesn't account for any two-digit number.

Comment: Now it doesn't account for single-digit numbers.

Comment: Thanks, the regex I wanted to use in the end is `/^([1-9]{1}][1-9][0-9]{1}|100)/`. Which is needed to match one digit numbers. ;) So why does the quantifier not work? It matches also 111?!?

Comment: @dollarvar Because none of the parts are optional, which is also the issue with Jerry's regex `^[1-9][0-9]$|^100$`. The question mark quantifier `?` makes parts of the expression optional. A `{1}` quantifier is absolutely redundant and doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Jerry Now you've copied my regex, but yes, it's correct. ;-)

Comment: Yeah Jerry, `$` at the end does the thing intuitively, have to get around why that is so though still. ;) But it is explained in your answer!! Let me accept it, sorry for the others. ;)

Comment: @dollarvar Ah, `$` matches the end of the line, so that if you have `^[1-9][0-9]?$` and say, 123 then the regex will match the `^` first (beginning of line), then the two numbers `1` and `2`, then tries to match the end of line, but it sees another number (3). The match thus fails.

Comment: I see, thanks. I know why I avoided up till now to use RegEx at all. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Your regular expression says to match any string that starts (because it's anchored at the beginning using `^`) with any digit between 1 and 9. This is why it doesn't match 0 or letters.

A range validation is something you'd want to check using basic number comparisons:

```
var numberValue = parseInt(this.value, 10);
if (numberValue >= 1 && numberValue <= 100) {
    // valid number
}
```

For the sake of completeness, you could create a regular expression for that purpose *which I don't recommend, though*:

```
^(?:[1-9][0-9]?|100)$
```

Comment: Thanks, I see. But I "need" to use a RegEx for that and still I wonder why the quantifier does not work?!?

Comment: @dollarvar The quantifier only says to match *exactly* one occurence of any digit between 1 and 9. Make sure not to mix up `[1-9]` with number range validation! It's just a shorthand notation for `[123456789]`.

Comment: I see. But how I get `[1-9]{1}` should match just one occurence of one digit between 1 and 9? Am I right?

Comment: @dollarvar True, but so does `[1-9]`. `{1}` is redundant and unnecessary, just like adding 0 to something or multiplying something by 1 (at least within the real numbers).

Comment: But why does it not work without the `$` at the end, as Jerry pointed out? The `^` at the beginning should do the same thing, nah?

Comment: @dollarvar Put simply, the `^` matches the beginning of the string, while the `$` matches its end. Without the so-called anchor `$`, you're only saying that your string needs to *start* with any number between 1 and 100, making e.g. `42foobar` a valid input. By appending `$`, you're ensuring there's nothing after the number.

Comment: Along with you. Regex is not the right instrument for solving math-related stuff, sure a lot is doable with regex, but it can also complicate things.